# Plot polar plot on top of image?

Tags: image, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a polar plot on top of an image. Here is the code I have, I just can't get the polar plot to be transparent so that the picture is seen underneath:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv


r = list(csv.reader(open('avg.csv','r')))
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 73)
img = plt.imread("voltage_abs.png")
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img, zorder=0)
ax.imshow(img)

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_ylim(30,41)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(30,41,2))
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_rlabel_position(-22.5)  # get radial labels away from plotted line
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_title("Polar", va='bottom')
plt.savefig('polar.pdf',bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you remove the `[r]` tag, this appears to have everything to do with your variable named `r` and nothing to do with the [R programming language](http://r-project.org/).

Comment: I suggest you add `numpy` and `matplotlib` tags to draw attention from the folk who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial solution:

Create two axes manually, on top of each other, one to display the image, and the other to display the polar plot. The trick is to make the background patch of the polar axis transparent via `ax_polar.path.set_alpha(0)`. I believe the problem with the approach in the question is that `imshow` is not behaving nicely when used on a polar-projection axis, so no amount of playing with `alpha`/`zorder` will make it work as desired.

Unsolved issues: To see both the background image and the polar plot, I needed to make the image transparent (`ax_image.imshow(img, alpha = .5)`). I bet there's a way to play with the `zorder` of various plot elements to avoid this, but I wasn't able to make it happen.

Also, the image extends beyond the polar plot. This could probably be fixed by adding a patch with the right shape and `zorder` to block the undesired parts of the image, but I'm not sure what the question asker wants with regards to that.

It should look something like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

r = list(csv.reader(open('avg.csv', 'r')))
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 73)
img = plt.imread("voltage_abs.png")

fig = plt.gcf()

axes_coords = [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8]

ax_polar = fig.add_axes(axes_coords, projection = 'polar')
ax_polar.patch.set_alpha(0)
ax_polar.plot(theta, r)
ax_polar.set_ylim(30, 41)
ax_polar.set_yticks(np.arange(30, 41, 2))
ax_polar.set_yticklabels([])
ax_polar.set_rlabel_position(-22.5)  # get radial labels away from plotted line
ax_polar.grid(True)
ax_polar.set_title("Polar", va = 'bottom')

ax_image = fig.add_axes(axes_coords)
ax_image.imshow(img, alpha = .5)
ax_image.axis('off')  # don't show the axes ticks/lines/etc. associated with the image

plt.savefig('polar.pdf', bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.show()
```

Fiddling with the axis ticks/labels/title/etc. will likely be necessary to make everything look nice.

Incidentally, in case anyone lands here looking for how to do this for rectangular axes, you don't need to do the two-axes trick: just `imshow` on the same axes you're plotting on and set the `alpha`/`zorder` appropriately.

Comment: This is perfect! With a few tweaks this works! Thank you very much.