# Plotting an image as background of a polar projection scatterplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, projection

I am programming a darts bot. It is calculated where the bot hit the board and now I want to visualize this using matplotlib.

What I have:
Displaying the position where the bot hit the board with a regular polar projection with axis and stuff.

What I need:
Setting a dartboard as background and plotting the X&Y (or theta & r respectively) on top.

What I tried:
Joining my piece of code together with the accepted answer of: [Plot polar plot on top of image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830164/plot-polar-plot-on-top-of-image)

This is what my code looks like now:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# throw three darts:
rad = np.asarray([10000, 11000, 9400]) # consider these as distances from bull's eye in 10*µm
azi = np.asarray([352, 0, 10]) # in degrees
azi = np.deg2rad(azi) # conversion into radians

fig = plt.gcf()

axes_coords = [0, 0, 1, 1] # plotting full width and height

ax_polar = fig.add_axes(axes_coords, projection='polar')
ax_polar.patch.set_alpha(0)
ax_polar.scatter(azi, rad)
ax_polar.set_ylim(0, 17000)
ax_polar.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
ax_polar.set_theta_offset(0.5*np.pi) # 0° should be on top, not right
ax_polar.set_theta_direction(direction=-1) # clockwise

plt.show()
```

The above code works fine. If you run it, you will see that the bot hit close to T20 field which is located straight above bull's eye.

Now if I want to add the image, I insert the following code before `plt.show()`

```
pic = plt.imread('Board_cd.png')
ax_image = fig.add_axes(axes_coords)
ax_image.imshow(pic, alpha=.5)
ax_image.axis('off')  # don't show the axes ticks/lines/etc. associated with the image
```

The picture looks like this:
[image: Dartboard]

But the result isn't very satisfying:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without looking in detail into the code here, I seems this is similar to [How to add Roulette Wheel background image to matplotlib Radar Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554591/how-to-add-roulette-wheel-background-image-to-matplotlib-radar-chart).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately for me, the solution to the question you posted was to recreate the background by matplot itself which is hardly possible for my case ...

Comment: I guess it's fine if you say that you don't want to do that due to whatever reason; but it is sure possible.

Comment: Well, a solution without an image would always be preferred. Maybe I will dig deeper into this, but at the moment I don't think I can cope with this task. But you are right - I should keep it in mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the code you show in the question you should get a warning

> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.

The solution is already given inside the warning, namely to give the axes a unique label, e.g.

```
ax_polar = fig.add_axes(axes_coords, projection='polar', label="ax polar")
# ...
ax_image = fig.add_axes(axes_coords, label="ax image")
```

The resulting dart board should then look like

[image]

Comment: I don't get any warnings ... that's odd. Using Anaconda python 3.6.4 in PyCharm at the moment. Anyways, the solution is great and seems to work perfectly! From here on I will be able to do the fine-tuning. Thank you!

Comment: I find that message really confusing, the first axis has `projection='polar'` while the second doesn't, so one might argue they don't have the same arguments... Anyway, I'd suggest using `zorder` (e.g. `zorder=-99` in the second `add_axes` call) instead of `label` so you get both different arguments and proper z stacking of the axes